# React re-map results in empty Array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create re-map an Array - to create a new Array on each loop and assign it to `series`

Instead, I can see in the console six empty arrays (from the `console.log` output)
Why is the array empty, and why does it iterate 6 times rather than 3?

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {

  const data  = [
    {
      "record": [
        [
          "Conferencing",
          "1",
          "8"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "record": [
        [
          "Expenses",
          "514",
          "6"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "record": [
        [
          "Mobiles",
          "717",
          "2"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ];

  const [series, setSeries] = React.useState([]);


  React.useEffect(() =>{
    data.map((o, idx) => {
      var rec = o.record[0];
      setSeries(...series, { product: rec[0], sales: Number(rec[1]) } );
      console.log(series)
    } )
  },[]);


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wlxkgq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it enables [StrictMode](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-re-running-effects-in-development) and it will re-run Effect

> When Strict Mode is on, React will also run one extra setup+cleanup cycle in development for every Effect

Remove `<StrictMode/>` component to turn off strict mode.

**UPDATE:**

Why `console.log` after `setSeries()` does not print the latest state? Take a look at this question: [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Instead of calling `setSeries` function multiple times even though React will [batch the state updates](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#react-batches-state-updates), calling it once after computing the new state is better.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      record: [['Conferencing', '1', '8']],
    },
    {
      record: [['Expenses', '514', '6']],
    },
    {
      record: [['Mobiles', '717', '2']],
    },
  ];

  const [series, setSeries] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const newSeries = data.map((o, idx) => {
      var rec = o.record[0];
      return { product: rec[0], sales: Number(rec[1]) };
    });
    setSeries(newSeries);
  }, []);
  console.log(series);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Actually, you don't need to use `useEffect` in this example, you can use the initializer function of the `useState()` hook to compute the `series` state. See [Avoiding recreating the initial state](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#avoiding-recreating-the-initial-state)

```js
import React from 'react';

const data = [
  {
    record: [['Conferencing', '1', '8']],
  },
  {
    record: [['Expenses', '514', '6']],
  },
  {
    record: [['Mobiles', '717', '2']],
  },
];

const initSeries = () => {
  return data.map((o, idx) => {
    var rec = o.record[0];
    return { product: rec[0], sales: Number(rec[1]) };
  });
};
export default function App() {
  const [series, setSeries] = React.useState(initSeries);
  console.log(series);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-eyw6fc?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: thanks, that explains why it ran twice.  I'm still confused why `series` is empty

Comment: Perfect! I'm learning